# RabbitMQ exchange gets filled and instantly emptied

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, rabbitmq

I have a school project to use RabbitMQ and events. I followed the guide by RabbitMQ for topics in javascript and it seemed to work. My teacher asked if I could publish something and show it in RabbitMQ, to see if it was there. When I looked at the exchange a saw a publish, but it also looked like it was consumed. The weird thing is that I didn't have any consumers at that moment.

I have tried setting durable and persistence true and false, as well as exclusive for the consumer. I can't really find anything about it on the internet.

This is the code I use to publish something to RabbitMQ:

```
        amqp.connect('amqp://quest:quest@localhost', function(error0, connection) {
            if (error0) {
                throw error0;
            }
            connection.createChannel(function(error1, channel) {
                if (error1) {
                    throw error1;
                }
                console.log(routingKey);
                console.log(msg);

                channel.assertExchange(exchange, 'topic', {
                    durable: false,
                    persistent: false
                });
                channel.publish(exchange, routingKey, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(msg)));
                console.log(" [x] Sent %s: '%s'", routingKey, msg);
            });

            setTimeout(function() {
                connection.close();
            }, 500);
        });
    }
```

I know the publish works, but I can't figure out why it is consumed/deleted automatically without consumers or anything. I think it should stay in the exchange. If I am wrong please correct me. I am new to this.

Comment: Is there any queue bound to this exchange? If not, the message is discarded as unroutable.

Comment: Do I also have to assert and bind a queue to this exchange then?

Comment: Any message that can not be routed to a queue is discarded. Yes, you will have to create and bind at least one queue.

Comment: Okay I have it working know, thank you. I have another problem that when my consumer is created it creates a new queue instead of listening on existing ones. I don't give a name to the queue, so it is generated by RabbitMQ. Is there a way to bins this queue to existing queues without knowing its name? It is connected to right exchange.

Comment: No, you will have to know the name of the queue if you want to bind to it. What is the use case?

Comment: I have to be able to register a patient (for a hospital) when it is written to the write database I have to send it to the RabbitMQ queue using a messaging pattern (we chose topics) there are a few other services listening on certain exchanges or queues. We have to create microservices and use docker.